# How to extract subjects from the email headers using regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex, email

I just start learning regex and encounter a problem when extracting subjects from the email headers.

In order to only keep the subjects of each header and also neglect "Re:" and "Fwd:" (case insensitive), I use the following regex which is able to highlight all useless parts.

```
/(Subject: *)?(\bRE|FWD?)([:\[][0-9]?[ :\]]*)/ig
```

But, I am unable to extract the real subjects I want.

```
Subject: Re: re[2]: RSVP

Subject: Re: Fwd: Direct Access Application

Subject: RE:

Subject: RE: Proposed Negotiation Strategy

Subject: RE: Re: RE:      Case study option

Subject:     RE: Staffing
```

I tried re.sub(...), but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close!  What you want to do is use capture groups to get at the part of the match you want.  Here is your regex slightly modified:

```
/(?:Subject:\s*)?(?:\bRE|FWD?)(?:[:\[][0-9]?[ :\]]*)(.*)/ig
```

So, you'll notice the 3 `?:` in there.  That means the match within those parentheses will not be captured by the regex engine into a group.  However, the last part will be: `(.*)`

That last part is what you want, and is in the first capture group of the match.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of "?:". However, the regex you provide can  only exclude one "Re:" or "Fwd:" ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version of the regex.

```
import re
text = [
 'Subject: Re: re[2]: RSVP',
 'Subject: Re: Fwd: Direct Access Application',
 'Subject: RE:',
 'Subject: RE: Proposed Negotiation Strategy',
 'Subject: RE: Re: RE:      Case study option',
 'Subject:     RE: Staffing'
]

p = re.compile('([\[\(] *)?.*(RE?S?|FWD?|re\[\d+\]?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*|$)|\]+ *$', re.IGNORECASE)
for line in text:
    print(p.sub('', line).strip())
```

This will give you the following output:

```
RSVP
Direct Access Application

Proposed Negotiation Strategy
Case study option
Staffing
```

Here is the explanation:

```
([\[\(] *)?             # starting [ or (, followed by optional spaces
.*(RE|FWD|re\[\d\]?) *  # Anything before RE or FW or FWD or re[number], followed by optional spaces
([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]+ $)  # only count it as a Re or FWD if it is followed by 
                        # : or - or ; or ] or ) or end of line
                        # (and after that you can have more of these symbols with
                        #  spaces in between)
|                       # OR
\]+ *$                  # match any trailing \] at end of line 
                        # (we assume the brackets () occur around a whole Re/Fwd
                        #  but the square brackets [] occur around the whole 
                        #  subject line)
```

Hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps (i think there's some issues in your regex but I can't work it out), but in Python, you don't use `/ig` to pass flags, you do it like this:

```
re.sub('(Subject: *)?(\bRE|FWD?)([:\[][0-9]?[ :\]]*)', 
       subjectstring, '', flags = re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Your solution works when switching subjectstring and ''